# Why is this Vue prop not reacting to change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Prop in my component that is a User object, I then have this function:

```
    onChange: function(event){
        this.$v.$touch();
        if (!this.$v.$invalid) {
            this.$axios.put('update',{
                code:this.user.code,
                col:event.target.name,
                val:event.target.value  
            }).then(response => {
                this.user[event.target.name]=event.target.value
            });
        }
    }
```

I can see in the Vue console debugger that the correct attribute has been updated, **this attribute exists when the component is created** but the template where I reference it does not refresh:

```
<p>Hi {{user.nickname}}, you can edit your details here:</p>
```

This is all within the same component so I'm not navigating to child or parent. I'm sure props have been reactive elsewhere in my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, it seems this is intended behaviour.  According to the documentation
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html in the scenario that I have it should be handled as:

> 1. **The prop is used to pass in an initial value; the child component wants to use it as a local data property afterwards.** In this case,
>    it’s best to define a local data property that uses the prop as its
>    initial value:
>
>    ```
>     props: ['initialCounter'],
>     data: function () {
>       return {
>         counter: this.initialCounter
>       }
>     }
>    ```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, components should be reactive to Props, though I have had experiences where it was non-reactive, so I added the prop to a watcher and put the functional call there.

```
props: ["myProp"],
watch:{
  myProp(){
     // ... your functions here
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is I'm trying to have a single function deal with any change on the object.  I added the watch on User with Deep but it didn't fire when I changed the input.  Which is also weird though, so there must be something missing.  I'll create a fiddle to see if I can recreate...

Comment: Please share it here then

Comment: Yeah, didn't get that far, discovered the answer in the Docs, so have now posted that (I'll have to check the rest of my code for where I thought this was working as it may not be reliable)