# Props gotten directly from vue 3 setup are not reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, reactive, vue-props

I am writing an application in vuejs and i want to pass prop to a child component but I am getting this error:

> Getting a value from the `props` in root scope of `setup()` will cause the value to lose reactivity

Parent component

```html
<template>
  <div>
      <course-list :courseId = "id"  />
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
import {useRoute} from 'vue-router';
import { ref, onMounted, reactive} from 'vue';
export default defineComponent({
  components: { NavBar, CourseList, CourseContent },
  props:{
    courseId: String
  },
  setup(){
      const route = useRoute()

      const id = route.params.id
      console.log("the course id is", id);

    return{
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Child Component

```js
export default defineComponent({
  components: { CourseTopic },
  props: {
      courseId: {
        type: String
      }
    },
  setup(props) {

    const trainingCourseId = props.courseId;

    return { courses, trainingCourseId };
  },
});
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Could this be your solution? [Why is this Vue prop not reacting to change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360966/why-is-this-vue-prop-not-reacting-to-change). If not please share the error message as mentioned above.

Comment: @PeterKrebs The error message is in the question, but was somewhat hidden due to poor formatting. I've fixed that.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use [`toRefs()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#torefs) on `props` to keep the reactivity on the prop:

```js
import { toRefs } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup(props) {
    const { courseId: trainingCourseId } = toRefs(props)
    return { trainingCourseId }
  }
}
```

Or [`toRef()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#toref):

```js
import { toRef } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup(props) {
    const trainingCourseId = toRef(props, 'courseId')
    return { trainingCourseId }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 24):

```
const trainingCourseId = props.courseId;
```

All it says is that your `trainingCourseId` is not reactive, meaning if the parent component passes in a different `courseId`, your `trainingCourseId` will **NOT** have the new value (**to be super clear, `props.courseId` will be updated, it is just your `trainingCourseId` not updating**).

I guess the code you posted is just for demonstration, because in this specific case you can actually just use `courseId` (in your template) directly, and it will be reactive.

However the bigger question remains - why `courseId` is reactive but `trainingCourseId` is not? Doesn't the doc say that the props is a reactive object? How exactly is reactivity destroyed here?

Just to be clear, reassigning a property to a local variable does not always remove *all of* the reactivity (yes, some reactivity will always be lost, but depending on the shape of the property, the loss of reactivity might not be that obvious initially).

Vue 3 uses **Proxy** to achieve reactivity. The idea is that for the given raw data object: `{ courseId: "something" }`, Vue creates another Proxy object that looks just like the given data object but with all the property getters and setters **intercepted**. The reactivity comes from these intercepted getters and setters, and hence is associated with the object owning the getters and setters, not the property itself.

In other words:

```
const raw = { courseId: "something" };
const rxData = reactive(raw);
```

What is reactive is the rxData, not the courseId, meaning any access to the rxData properties (any property, doesnt have to be courseId) is reactive. However, when you do `const trainingCourseId = rxData.courseId`, `trainingCourseId` is not a Proxy, it is just a string (retrieved out of a proxy).

This is a little bit different when courseId is not a simple string but an object:

```
const raw = { courseId: { name: "something" } };
const rxData = reactive(raw);
const trainingCourseId = rxData.courseId;
```

When building the reactive proxy, Vue recursively converts the original raw data object. Hence rxData.courseId is actually also a Proxy in this case. If you change the courseId name by `rxData.courseId.name = "something else"`, the change will be reflected in trainingCourseId. However, if you reassign rxData.courseId by `rxData.courseId = { name: "something else" }`, this reassignment will not be visible to trainingCourseId.

The toRef and toRefs method mentioned in the other answer will help you get rid of all these funny behaviors. But if you are interested you can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66585688/what-is-the-difference-between-ref-toref-and-torefs/67617646#67617646) about vue3 reactivity

Answer (score 12):

Aditionally to toRef() and toRefs(), one can compute props to get'em reactive.

Example using typescript setup:

```
import { computed } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  prop1: {
    type: String
  },
  prop2: {
   type: Boolean,
   default: () => false
  }
})

const prop1 = computed(() => props.prop1)
const prop2 = computed(() => props.prop2)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
interface IProps {
  prop1: string;
  prop2?: string;
}

let { prop1 = "Prop1 default value", prop2 } = defineProps<IProps>();

rProp1 = $$(prop1) //get reactive
```